# Creating a function that has button with the value of sender

Tags: c#

i'm creating a Graphical Calculator in C# and uses this to display the button pressed in the text box.

```
Button b = (Button)sender;
result_text.Text = result_text.Text + b.Text;
inumber2 = double.Parse(result_text.Text);
```

and i'm looking to make it a function so i can call that instead of having the exact same code 10 times over in my project.

The object sender just sends the numerical value that is pressed in the calculator and Visual Studio presents me with this error:

"The name 'sender' does not exist in the current context"

EDIT:

"result_text.Text" is the text box that displays the numbers pressed to the user.

Comment: *"The name 'sender' does not exist in the current context"* simply means that there is no variable named `sender` visible in the scope where you placed that code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it an event handler and bind every button's click event to the same handler:

```
private void AnyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  Button b = (Button)sender;
  result_text.Text = result_text.Text + b.Text;
  inumber2 = double.Parse(result_text.Text);
}
```

You can either bind events visually on the forms designer- select all ten buttons, click properties grid lightnight boot icon, find Click, drop down to reveal AnyButton_Click and choose it

Or you can bind them in code, in the form constructor, AFTER InitializeComponent has been called:

```
oneButton.Click += AnyButton_Click;
twoButton.Click += AnyButton_Click;
...
```